# How to solve this issue my app is running in Simulator but crashing on iphone device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash, ios-simulator

Here, I am attaching the crash report. My application is in swift.

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 000000000000000 Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>   Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: abort() called`enter code here
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x000000018edca014
>   0x18edab000 + 126996 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x000000018ee91460 0x18ee8c000 + 21600 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x000000018ed3e3f4 0x18ecdb000 + 406516 3   libswiftCore.dylib
>     0x00000001002bdd80 0x100178000 + 1334656 4   libswiftCore.dylib
>     0x000000010029aefc 0x100178000 + 1191676 5   libswiftCore.dylib
>     0x000000010029af80 0x100178000 + 1191808 6   libswiftCore.dylib
>     0x00000001002bf6dc 0x100178000 + 1341148 7   Rajkot News
>     0x0000000100058650 0x100040000 + 99920 8   Rajkot News
>     0x00000001000595a4 0x100040000 + 103844 9   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x000000018ec851c0 0x18ec84000 + 4544 10  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x000000018ec92008 0x18ec84000 + 57352 11  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x000000018ec9e648 0x18ec84000 + 108104 12  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x000000018ec87164 0x18ec84000 + 12644 13  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x000000018ec89bc0 0x18ec84000 + 23488 14  CoreFoundation
>     0x000000018fda9f2c 0x18fccd000 + 905004 15  CoreFoundation
>     0x000000018fda7b18 0x18fccd000 + 895768 16  CoreFoundation
>     0x000000018fcd6048 0x18fccd000 + 36936 17  GraphicsServices
>     0x0000000191759198 0x19174d000 + 49560 18  UIKit
>     0x0000000195cb0628 0x195c35000 + 505384 19  UIKit
>     0x0000000195cab360 0x195c35000 + 484192 20  Rajkot News
>     0x000000010007b040 0x100040000 + 241728 21  libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018ecb85b8 0x18ecb4000 + 17848

Comment: you might want to check [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19859)

Comment: in which line you got this error? @Brijesh add code into your question

Comment: That's exactly i don't know but i think error is coming on 

"let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.01 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            self.fetch_category()
        }"
@Saranjith

Comment: Removed unnecessary crash log information.

Comment: thank you @Dipen Panchasara